# Help with code on integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

I'm trying to do a surface integral through a vector field of a disc. The problem says there is a vector field $\langle 0, y, -z\rangle$ and the disc is $x^2 + z^2 \le 1, y = 1$.

The answer is $\pi$ but I get $\pi/3$ each time. Hmmm... here's my code:

```
Clear[x, y, z]
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + z^2 <= 1 && y == 1, {x, y, z}];
Integrate[{0, y, -z } . 
  Normalize[Grad[1 - x^2 - z^2 , {x, y, z}], Sqrt[# . #] &], {x, y, z} ∈ region]
```

UPDATE:

In trying to the top of a cylinder, which is governed by a plane, I get stuck on this. The vector field is funky, x,y,5 (the problem gives that), and then I have a plane x+y=2 which is the top of a cylinder, x^2 + z^2 =1. The bottom is y =0/

```
Clear[x, y, z]
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + z^2 == 1 && y <= 2 - x , {x, y, z}];
Integrate[{x, y, 5 } . ?? ???????),{x,y,z}\[Element]region]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

```
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x + y - 2 == 0, {x, y, z}];
Integrate[{x, y, 5} . 
  Normalize[Grad[x + y - 2, {x, y, z}], Sqrt[# . #] &], {x, y, 
   z} ∈ region]
```

> `2π`

**Updated**

I found the error come from the normal of the surface $x^2+z^2\le1,\;y=1$ It should be
$(0,1,0)$ instead of  `Normalize[Grad[1 - x^2 - z^2 , {x, y, z}], Sqrt[# . #] &]`! Because we no reason to  consider the normal of the surface $1 - x^2 - z^2$, it is different from $x^2+z^2\le1,\;y=1$

```
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + z^2 <= 1 && y == 1, {x, y, z}];
Integrate[{0, y, -z} . {0, 1, 0}, {x, y, z} ∈ region]
```

> `π`

**Origninal**

```
x = r*Cos[θ];
y = 1;
z = r*Sin[θ];
f = {x, y, z};
F = {0, y, -z};
Integrate[
 F . Cross[D[f, r], D[f, θ]], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 
  2 π}]
```

According to the orientation.

> `-π`

Comment: Thanks so much. It would help me understand MMA better, too, if you could help me spot the error in the above code, too, which i think I got from you!

Comment: @Abcderia I think it is not easy to calculate the surface integral in $R^3$ by implicit form. I don't know what is the principle  inside function of MMA ,so here we just use the definition of surface integral.

Comment: @Abcderia see my updated.

Comment: Is this reasoning the same when you have planes that make the top and bottom of a surface, (say, on top and bottom of a cylinder)?

Comment: Is that change in the "integrate" line or the region line? So if I have a plane x+y =2 over a cylinder x^2 + z^2  = 1, and the vector field <x,y,5>, I wrote the following code, but it doesn't work.... Clear[x, y, z]
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + z^2 == 1 && y <= 2 - x , {x, y, z}];
Integrate[{x, y, 5 } . ?? ???????),{x,y,z}\[Element]region]

Comment: @Abcderia you can edit your question and the the new code.

Comment: Done, see update.